# WSO2 API Manager `filter` mediation not entered as it should

Tags: api

I am working to put an API behind WSO2 API Manager installed on premise. I designed the API, added the endpoint and add a first mediation sequence which add Authorization header at runtime. And it works fine.

Now I am improving that mediation sequence in other to obtain a token if it doesn't exist and to renew it when it expires. The obtained token is stored in the registry.
To do that, I use https://medium.com/@athiththan11/wso2-api-manager-oauth2-protected-endpoint-aa51c62f0ad7 and https://medium.com/@menakajayawardena/wso2-how-to-using-oauth2-protected-back-ends-with-api-manager-5d7e234c61c posts as reference.

My sequence is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="bapi_in_dev" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property description="Retrieve stored token data" expression="get-property('registry','gov:/bapi/token_data')" name="stored_token_data" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <property description="Retrieve the time token_data was generated" expression="get-property('registry', 'gov:/bapi/token_generation_time')" name="token_generation_time" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <filter description="Renouveller le token tmoney si il est vieux de plus d'une heure" xpath="fn:number(get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')) - fn:number(get-property('token_generation_time')) > fn:number(360000)">
        <then>
            <property description="Sauvegarde du body de la requete" expression="json-eval($)" name="client_request_body" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property description="Sauvegarde de la resource demandée" expression="get-property('axis2', 'REST_URL_POSTFIX')" name="client_request_resource" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <payloadFactory description="Body de la requete d'obtention de token" media-type="json">
                <format>{
    "nomUtilisateur": "username",
    "motDePasse": "password"
}</format>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
            <header description="Header requis par bapi" name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/json"/>
            <property description="Suppression  initialisation de la resource avant demande de token" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value=""/>
            <call blocking="true" description="Demande de token">
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="post" statistics="enable" trace="enable" uri-template="https://bapi.domain.tld/login">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <property description="Extraction du token" expression="json-eval($.data.token)" name="tm_resp_data" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property description="Enregistrement du token" expression="get-property('tm_resp_data')" name="gov:/bapi/token_data" scope="registry" type="STRING"/>
            <property description="Enregistrement heure a laquelle code a ete genere" expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')" name="gov:/bapi/token_generation_time" scope="registry" type="LONG"/>
            <property description="Configuration de la resource pour effectuer la requete de l'user" expression="get-property('client_request_resource')" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
            <header description="Ajout du token dans le header" expression="get-property('tm_resp_data')" name="Authorization" scope="transport"/>
            <payloadFactory description="Reconstruction du body de requete user" media-type="json">
                <format>$1</format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('client_request_body')"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
        </then>
        <else>
            <header description="Ajout de Authorization header sauvegardé" expression="get-property('stored_token_data')" name="Authorization" scope="transport"/>
        </else>
    </filter>
</sequence>
```

I add this mediation to the API's inflow. But when I query it, it daes not enter the `then` part of the sequence then not updating the token.

Can you help me see why the `filter` is working that way and what I should do to correct it?

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

The mediation sequence as describe was working.
The thing misleading me is that the call mediation part of the process was not displayed in the log (I have wire set to debug) as it does before I add the filter.

I also find that when I set `token_generation_time` type to `LONG` operation `fn:number(get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')) - fn:number(get-property('token_generation_time'))` result in a `NaN` which I don't understand.

```
<log level="custom">
        <property expression="fn:number(get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')) - fn:number(get-property('token_generation_time'))" name="FilterV"/>
    </log>
```

In log:

```
[2020-10-07 15:57:09,539]  INFO - LogMediator FilterV = NaN
```

My issue is resolved.
Thanks to everyone who read this post for his willing to help me.

But I am still interested in why of the NaN result above. I would also like to have some advises from you to improve the sequence. Thanks